# Opening a new window in silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

What is the difference in Silverlight 4 between calling System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("openWindow") where "openWindow" is a js function that calls window.open and calling System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.PopupWindow(someUri, "_blank", null)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that calling `window.open` is not a ratified standard.  The purpose of the `PopupWindow` method in the Silverlight API is to abstract variations of the implementation of `open` between browsers.

For example the property names used for open options may vary from browser to browser.  Using `PopupWindow` your code can use the strongly typed `HtmlPopupWindowOptions` class to define these options in a consistent way.  The silverlight runtime handles the making the request to the browser to perform the desired action in a way appropriate to the host browser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition PopupWindow will work with popup blocker if you opening popup in response to the user action.